# Extjs 5 Grid inside viewport horizontal scrolling issue

Tags: extjs5

I have a grid inside my viewport. Code is as shown below.

By giving a fixed width to my grid, I do not get a horizontal scrollbar for my grid.  autoScroll = true dosent help either.

If I remove the fixed width given to my grid or give a layout fixed to my viewport I am not able to resize my grid columns.

I want to be able to be able to resize my columns at will and also need an horizontal scroll bar.

Columns are added dynamically and minWidth, flex and maxWidth have been set for each of the columns

What can be done? Please help

Viewport.js

```
Ext.define('MyView.view.Viewport', {
 extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
 requires:['MyView.view.gridPanel'], 
 layout : 'fit',
 items:[{
          //width:7000,
          xtype:'gridPanel'

        }]

  });
```

gridPanel.js

```
Ext.define('MyView.view.gridPanel', {
   extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
   plugins: 'gridfilters',
   alias: 'widget.gridPanel',
   id: 'tests-view',
   name:'graphPanel',
   title: 'Tests',
   emptyText: '',
   store: 'MyView.store.settingStore',
   pageSize:10, 
   dockedItems: [{
     xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
     store: 'MyView.store.settingStore',   
     dock: 'bottom',
     displayInfo: true
  }],
  filters :[],
  //features:[],
  enableLocking:true,
  columns:[],  //Columns are loaded dynamically
  viewConfig: {
        stripeRows: true,
         plugins: {
            dragGroup: 'user-dd',
            enableDrop: false,
            ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop'
            //forceFit:true

        }
    },
columnLines: true,
frame: true

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scroll doesn't appear, because you have set grid width to 7000px. Usually scroll appears in grid when columns width is greater than grid width. Use layout to fit grid in parent container, or adjust its width, and then scroll should appear.

Comment: If i were to remove the fixed width 7000, and give a fit layout then I am not able to resize my columns in the grid. I cannot drag the columns and expand them. What can be done?